# Reseed an identity column after sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table 'TABLE1' with the following columns:

```
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(100),
col3 int identity(1,1)
```

I have performed some operations on this table to insert some data into it. Once complete, I want to reassign the value of col3 after sorting by col1 and col2. I have tried using the window function `row_number()` for this but it does not serve my purpose due to the following reason.

This table is a temporary table. Everyday, data is deleted from this table. On day 1, say there are 10 rows inserted into this table, I need col3 to have values 1 to 10. On day 2, since I am just truncating the data from this table, the data in col3 starts from 11 to 20. If I need to reseed this value on day 2, I would need to start from 11 and not from 1 and hence cannot use `row_number()`.

Is there any way to use a sort with the reseed functionality in SQL Server? Or what would be an alternative to solving this issue?

Comment: Why? What problem would that solve? Are you looking for [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) perhaps?

Comment: Identity columns automatically remain at the last number inserted, so on day 2 you *will* be inserting 11?

Comment: Yes, on day 2, I will be inserting 11. But after performing additional inserts, I want to re - sort the table based on col1 and col2 and assign values to col3 starting from 11.

Comment: Sounds like rather than using an `identity` you either need to manually run an update against the table or just use a `view` to give you the numbered ordering, to which you can then add any default offset?

Comment: You'd be better off not using an identity column in that case. Just use an int and update it to whatever you want.

Comment: Dale K - Thank you! I was leaning towards that but wanted to check if there was any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting your data from table you can run `DBCC CHECKIDENT` script with following properties below

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Shema].[Table]', RESEED, IdentityNumbertoStart);
```

You can read Microsoft article at link, [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)